# A schema mismatch detected when writing to the Delta table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I receive:

> **A schema mismatch detected when writing to the Delta table**

I tried to follow the suggestion:

> To overwrite your schema or change partitioning, please set:
> '.option("overwriteSchema", "true")'.

Based on this solution: [A schema mismatch detected when writing to the Delta table - Azure Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60915267/a-schema-mismatch-detected-when-writing-to-the-delta-table-azure-databricks)

- I added such an option, but it looks like it doesn't work or I simply
  did it improperly.
- I cleaned `dbfs:/delta-tables/_delta_log/`
- I tried even to remove the whole folder where I saved data
  (`dbfs:/FileStore/shared_upload/[user]/data_Delta`).

None of this has fixed the issue.
What I'm doing wrong?
And why it behaves in such a way if I want to reuse an old notebook with a new cluster, the old one I terminated, so it should be 'clean' as I guess?

**I proceed in the following way:**

1.I load data from GEN2. They are in parquet format this way:

```py
spark.read.option("overwriteSchema", "true")\
  .parquet(f"wasbs://{CONTAINER_NAME}@{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/data")
```

As you see I set `overwriteSchema` as `true`.

2.Then I save it in delta format:

```py
sd_weather.write.format('delta').mode("overwrite") \
  .save("dbfs:/FileStore/shared_upload/[user]/data_Delta")
```

3.Then I try to create Delta Table

```py
sd_weather.write.format('delta') \
  .mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("data_Delta")
```

And here I receive the error:

*AnalysisException: A schema mismatch detected when writing to the Delta table*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.option("overwriteSchema", "true")` in the write operation, not in the read one:

```py
sd_weather.write.format('delta').mode("overwrite") \
  .option("overwriteSchema", "true") \
  .save("dbfs:/FileStore/shared_upload/[user]/data_Delta")
```

You also writing your data twice, once as "normal" directory, second - as a managed table.  If you want to create unmanaged table in custom location, just add the `path` option to the 3rd variant (also, `dbfs:/` is default schema, so you may omit it):

```py
sd_weather.write.format('delta') \
  .option("overwriteSchema", "true") \
  .option("path", "/FileStore/shared_upload/[user]/data_Delta") \
  .mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("data_Delta")
```

Also, it depends on how different is the schema, if it just adds the columns or something like, then you can use `mergeSchema` instead of `overwriteSchema`.

Comment: Thanks, Alex (again) for helping me to learn Spark, and pointing out the mistake I made.